# Unable to login and Call SIP/VOIP library doubango with TLS for android?

Tags: android, call, sip, voip, sip-server

I am also new to NDK development and I am try to develope  application based on SIP/VOIP protocol.

[Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.arksol.arkfone&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5hcmtzb2wuYXJrZm9uZSJd)

etc.

After searching I found this library which used in application [library for app](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/)

And downloaded and managed code from the given example according to my need and on UDP protocol it works fine.

As calling on this way are block in some of country that's why I am trying to implement calling feature as encrypted.

And from douboungo library I setup **TLS** and Port **5061** for **sip2sip.info** account but I am not able to login or call with TLS setup.

Any one have an idea how to configure **TLS** with **doubango** framework.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.